# Toast not showing in onMessageReceived of FireBase Cloud Messaging Service

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

I have used below code to make Log,Toast and send broadcast to service from onMessageReceived.

I am able to see the data send using Firebase Console in the Log. But Toast is not showing and Broadcast is also not send.

Code below:

```
class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());

        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Toast shown",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setAction("firebase.message.combinedthings");
            sendBroadcast(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Note that it is not recommended to simply post data from services to the main thread (at least not without considering all possible consequences)... But, for the sake of testing:

The Toast is not being displayed because the onMessageReceived() code is not being executed on the main Thread... To show the Toast you should do that call on the UI Thread:

Kotlin version:

```
Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "FCM!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

Java version:

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
handler.post(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "FCM!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
});
```

I was having the same trouble, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing this problem for a long time and there are a few notable suggestions:
Firstly make sure you're adding the service to your app's manifest file:

```
<service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
    <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Secondly make sure that you've added:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

To your project level build.gradle under the buildscript > dependencies as well as:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

To the bottom of your app level build.gradle.
Finally nobody else recommended this but I tried it as a last resort, I made sure that every single one of my Firebase compiles were v9.4.0. Once I changed that it worked for me, so be sure to check that in your app level build.gradle as well (this is what mine looked like:)

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.1.1'
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My pupose solved I am able to sendBroadcast now, while Toast is now giving errors,so I removed the code for toast.